# Using Hexadecimal in Erlang

Tags: erlang, hex

Is there any way to convert a list of hexadecimal character to a `binary` that corresponds to the hexadecimal coding?

Example:

```erlang
[FF,AC,01]=><<255,172,1>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you meant this: `["FF","AC","01"] => <<255,172,1>>`.

You can use [list_to_integer/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_integer-2) function. It takes number base as second argument.

```
Hexs = ["FF","AC","01"],
Ints = [list_to_integer(Hex, 16) || Hex <- Hexs],
%% [255,172,1]
Binary = list_to_binary(Ints).
%% <<255,172,1>>
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the accepted answer is to go directly to binary via a binary comprehension:

```
1> Hexs = ["FF","AC","01"].
2> << <<(list_to_integer(C,16)):8>> || C <- Hexs >>.
<<255,172,1>>
```